# Joomla 3 configuration value

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

Being new to Joomla the following took me some time to figure out:

This does **not** work for me:

```
$config = JFactory::getConfig();
$mf = $config->get('config.mailfrom');
```

The following **does** work:

```
$config = JFactory::getConfig();
$mf = $config->get('mailfrom');
```

Is this a configuration issue in my Joomla installation or should I update the Joomla documentation [here](http://docs.joomla.org/Sending_email_from_extensions)?

Btw, I am using Joomla 3.3.

Comment: Do you happen to know where I can go to see the whole list of values I can get? (apart from 'mailfrom'). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm using joomla 3.4.3 and below code is working for me.

```
$config = & JFactory::getConfig();
$mf = $config->get('mailfrom');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use below syntax to get configuration values of Joomla.

```
$app        = JFactory::getApplication();
$mailfrom   = $app->getCfg('mailfrom');
```

This will work with almost all Joomla versions.

Comment: Ok, I will look into this as well. I guess the issue above is just a Joomla 2 vs Joomla 3 documentation thing...?

Comment: Note that `getCfg()` is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

I got here and for me this is working get('mailfrom')
getCfg is no longer a supported method.